# Some Pyramid + AJAX (Jquery) questions

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, pylons, pyramid

1. In my Pyramid package directory, if I create a file called `somefunction.py` and I want to call this function using $.post, what URL would I specify to call this function?
2. If I have a view function called `aview` created in `views.py`, can I call this function by simply referring the $.post url as `/aview/`.

(script files reside in the static folder)

Comment: read up on how requests get routed to view callables. the answer really depends on many things (routes vs traversal, imperative config vs declarative config) but you should really get a handle on this to use pyramid effectively.

Answer (score 3):

In both cases you have to write the proper routing configuration that maps the view (that has to contain the function you want to call) to a given url. You even have a xhr parameter to further customize the request [1]. I should clarify btw that I'm more a dispatcher than a traversal guy so my answer applies to that style of configuration

[1] http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/1.0/api/config.html#pyramid.config.Configurator.add_route

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am using url_dispatch. I have done as follows: In the init.py: I have added: `config.add_route('ajax', '/ajax/', view='testproject.views.ajax')`

In the views.py:

   `def ajax(request):
       string = 'hello world'
       return Response(string)`
Okay, so this works, but am I setting up the view and add_route
correctly. Is this how it is suppose to be done?

Thanks.
Awais,